# "airmon-ng start wlan0" not working

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng

I have a major problem on my Nethunter. Whenever I try to run "airmon-ng start wlan0" or "airmon-ng check kill" this happens;

```text
Error: /proc must be mounted
  To mount /proc at boot you need an /etc/fstab line like:
      proc   /proc   proc    defaults
  In the meantime, run "mount proc /proc -t proc"

Requested device "wlan0" does not exist.
Run /usr/sbin/airmon-ng without any arguments to see available interfaces
```

Edit: "airmon-ng" working properly. I can see the interfaces.

I searched a lot and... Nothing. Im stuck with this problem. I already saw a lot questions as same as mine but answers was outdated.
Edit: the output of sudo ls -la /proc

```
drwx------  21 root root 3488 Feb  3 10:27 ..
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root root    0 Feb  4 22:02 6642
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 6777
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 6780
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 6798
dr-xr-xr-x   9 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 6799
-r--r--r--   1 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 NVTSPI
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 aed
-dr-xr-xr-x   4 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 asound
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 atf_log
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 battery
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? battery_status
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? bcctlmt
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? boot_mode
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 bootdevice
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? bootprof
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? border_suppression
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? buddyinfo
-dr-xr-xr-x   3 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 bus
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? ccci_dump
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? ccci_log
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? cgroups
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 charger
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 chip
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? clkdbg
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 clkmgr
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 cm_mgr
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? cmdline
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? config.gz
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? consoles
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 cpu_loading
dr-xr-xr-x   5 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 cpufreq
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 cpuhvfs
-r--r--r--   1 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 cpuinfo
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? crypto
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? ddr_info
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? devapc_dbg
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   29 Feb  4 22:03 device-tree -> /sys/firmware/devicetree/base
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? devices
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? diskstats
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 dpe
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 drcc
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 driver
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 eem
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? execdomains
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? f2fs_status
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? fb
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? filesystems
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? fm
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? fpsensor
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 freqhopping
dr-xr-xr-x   6 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 fs
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 Jan 29 16:38 ged
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? gesture_function
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? gesture_state
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 golden
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 gpufreq
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? interrupts
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? iomem
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? ioports
dr-xr-xr-x 129 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 irq
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 isp_p2
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? kallsyms
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? key-users
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? keys
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? kmsg
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? kpagecgroup
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? kpagecount
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? kpageflags
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? last_kmsg
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? loadavg
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? locks
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? m4u
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mali
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mcdi
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mdpm
--r--r--r--   1 root root    0 Jan 29 17:18 meminfo
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? misc
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mobile_tm
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? modules
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   11 Feb  4 22:03 mounts -> self/mounts
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? mrdump_rst
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? msdc_debug
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? msdc_help
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mt-auxadc
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mt_power_gs
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mtk-perf
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mtk_battery_cmd
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mtk_cmdq_debug
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? mtk_jpeg
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mtkcooler
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mtktz
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? mtprintk
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 mtprof
-lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Feb  4 22:03 net -> self/net
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? nvt_baseline
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? nvt_diff
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? nvt_fw_version
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? nvt_raw
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? nvt_selftest
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? pagetypeinfo
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? partitions
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 pbm
dr-xr-xr-x   4 root root    0 Jan 29 16:38 perfmgr
dr-xr-xr-x   4 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 picachu
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? pidmap
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? pl_lk
dr-xr-xr-x   5 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 ppm
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Jan 29 16:38 pressure
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 resource_monitor
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? rid
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? rlkdevinfo
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? sched_debug
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? schedstat
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 scp_dvfs
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 scsi
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? sdcard_intr_gpio_value
-lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    0 Jan  1  1970 self -> 6799
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? softirqs
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? stat
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? swaps
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 swpm
dr-xr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 sys
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? sysrq-trigger
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? tasks_all
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? tasks_rq
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? thermlmt
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    0 Jan  1  1970 thread-self -> 6799/task/6799
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? timer_list
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? tkv
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? tkv_recovery
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 tran_chg_limit_current
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 tran_dvfsrc
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 tran_gc_debug
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? tran_mmc_cid
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 tran_release_wakelock
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? ttpct
-dr-xr-xr-x   4 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 tty
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 udi
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 uid
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? uid_concurrent_active_time
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? uid_concurrent_policy_time
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 uid_cputime
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 uid_io
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 uid_procstat
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? uid_time_in_state
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 upower
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? uptime
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? version
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? vmallocinfo
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? vmstat
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? wdk
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 wlan
-dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Feb  4 22:03 wmt_tm
--?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? zoneinfo
-?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? zraminfo
```

Comment: Did you (or a buggy script) change the permissions of /proc and /sys?
First find out why you can't access proc `sudo ls -la /proc`.
This might show you the files and permission in of the '/proc' dir.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right. The command " sudo ls -la /proc" looks a little buggy. But i don't know what to do.

Comment: Ummm, the proc file permission look correct. But I have never seen "?" from the ls command. Check your file permission for `/sys/class/net` the same way.

Comment: Output of "sudo ls -la /sys/class/net" ```drwx------ 2 root root 3488 Feb  1 10:21 .
drwx------ 3 root root 3488 Feb  1 10:21 ..```

Comment: well that is your issue. You can't access the /sys/class/net dir because of the permission. 
either fix your system permission or run as sudo ie `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0`

Comment: Reinstall your system, you have changed the permissions of a various files and directories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can access the /sys but now i have another major problem. As you can see i need to mount the proc but when i try to mount it output is: "mount: /proc: mount(2) system call failed: Function not implemented."